# why i can not send the json string to server in c#?

Tags: c#, json

I want to send json string to server ,first i write this json:

```
string json = "{\"registration_ids\":[\"" + regId + "\"]}";
```

server get up json successful,but when i change that to this:

```
string json = "{\"registration_ids\":[\"" + regId + "\"] , \"data\":[\"" + ns + "\"]}";
```

now don't send that json ,and i get this error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

what happen?how can i solve that?

```
string ns = "ali";
```

```
string regId = "APA91bGUgyf8rIVBIdRyc9JUZDWfBTBkflRB2xKe5u9zfd6xP8PYR0yWHXoA7_ev51bAuGHYLjzYuC-TwbzmfO35synRkjf5UoRTTMMYmKgi7qRgb6HPbIv9JFf_xLNd1IKKwriPUl3vCdGYtPMJj42GJir-";
```

Comment: You need to show more code so that people can help. For example how is `ns` created what data does it hold. It could be that this is causing the string to be invalid JSON. It could also mean that you don't have a method in `c#` that doesn't match the parameters you have specified

Comment: It all depends what the remote server is expecting... clearly it thinks the JSON you sent was invalid, as to why that is, that's almost impossible to predict. edit: as Flexicoder says knowing what 'ns' is would possibly help

Comment: @Flexicoder i update my question please review.

Comment: @CallumBradbury ok,please tell me valid JSON,thanks.

Comment: [] mean array in JSON, try doing this: "{\"registration_ids\":\"" + regId + "\" , \"data\":\"" + ns + "\"}";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're *probably* creating an invalid JSON. Don't "hand write" your JSON like that. Instead, use libraries that do this for you, like [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for example:

```
public class X
{
    [JsonProperty("registration_ids")]
    public List<string> RegistrationIds { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<string> Data { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = new X
    {
        RegistrationIds = new List<string> { "1", "2" },
        Data = new List<string> { "hello" }
    };
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x));
}
```

Will yield:

```
{"registration_ids":["1","2"],"data":["hello"]}
```

Comment: thanks my friend,but in this line:JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x).Dump(); visual studio don't know Dump();

Comment: @mohammadrezapoushideh Yes, I've removed the `Dump()`, it's from LINQPad :). Use `Console.WriteLine` instead.